# Rails CanCan hash of conditions access denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I'm having an issue setting up an ability that looks like this:

```
can :read, Project, :allocate_to => user.id
```

The problem is

```
ability.can?(:read, my_project)
```

returns false even though

```
Project.accessible_by(ability)
```

returns just the projects for that user as expected.

I've tried cancan 1.6.10 and cancancan 1.9.2 on rails 3.2.19 with ruby 1.9.3-p547

Is this a bug with cancancan or my code? How do I find out why ability.can?(:read, my_project) is failing?

[Also posted as an issue](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/121)

Comment: I'm going to work around this by using authorize_resource instead of load_and_authorize_resource in my controller. This will force it to work with the class instead of the object. I think it's related to [ryanb/cancan#213](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/213)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into issues using the hash notation in cancan with abilities like this one.  Have you tried:

```
can :read, Project do |project|
  project.allocate_to == user.id
end
```

I'm not sure why this is the case, but this has worked for me from time to time.